# How to change the file manager from Nautilus to Marlin

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, filemanager, marlin

I want to try out the Marlin file manager in 11.10 and want to know how to go about it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**To install Marlin in 11.10, enter the following commands in Terminal:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marlin-devs/marlin-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install marlin
```

*Source: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/elementary-file-browser-marlin-is-now.html*

**Once Marlin has been installed, follow these instructions to set it as your default file manager:**

Open Marlin → Edit → Preferences → click Make my default file manager

*Source: http://ubuntuportal.com/marlin-fast-file-browser-and-low-resource-2/*