# Marlin and integration of various VCS?

Tags: 11.10, version-control, marlin

I just stumbled in another question (http://askubuntu.com/questions/86749/how-to-change-the-file-manager-from-nautilus-to-marlin) upon the filemanager "Marlin".

I tried it a bit, and it seems to suit me more than Nautilus. except one tiny thing...

I had Nautilus-integrators for SVN, GIT, Bazaar, Mercurial, CVS. Not as a replacement for the commandline tools, but I wanted to see the status of a file in the filebrowser.

Are there Plugins for Marlin that have at least these status icons? Context menu for the various VCS is not needed but would be nice for quickaccess.

Comment: Alpha software is Alpha.. Marlin isn't beta what did you expected.

Comment: Since I cant even find a homepage, it is not very easy to gether such information. So from where should I know that it is alpha?

Comment: The Launchpad page for Marlin or elementary project, the elementary OS site, certainly here, OMG Ubuntu, their respective Facebook pages...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at the moment (as far as I know).

The [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~marlin-devs/+archive/marlin-daily) contains only 2 integration plugins: UbuntuOne and Dropbox. Those are created and maintained at the moment by the developers of Marlin.

Marlin is still under (heavy) development and one would expect some plugins to show up in the future but not at the same level as Nautilus. The plugins from Nautilus will not (as you might know) work with Marlin.

Marlin is a very recent project if you compare it with Nautilus, I am guessing it is just a mater of time and future support. I really love Marlin and hope the developers keep up the great work. Maybe (one can only hope that) we will see more plugins incoming soon.